# Spark: grouping rows in array by key

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a spark dataset like this one:

```
key id val1 val2 val3
1   a  a1   a2   a3
2   a  a4   a5   a6
3   b  b1   b2   b3
4   b  b4   b5   b6
5   b  b7   b8   b9
6   c  c1   c2   c3
```

I would like to group all rows by id in a list or array like this:

```
(a, ([1   a  a1   a2   a3], [2   a  a4   a5   a6]) ),
(b, ([3   b  b1   b2   b3], [4   b  b4   b5   b6], [5   b  b7   b8   b9]) ),
(c, ([6   c  c1   c2   c3]) )
```

I have used map to output key/value pairs with the right key but I have troubles in building the final key/array.

Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("combined",array("key","id","val1","val2","val3")).groupby("id").agg(collect_list($"combined"))
```

The Array function converts the columns into an array of column and then its a simple groupby with collect_list

Comment: This looks good.
I have changed the code to select all columns:

   df.withColumn("combined",array( df.columns map col: _*)).groupby("id").agg(collect_list($"combined"))

Is there any more concise way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On top of giving a good answer, Assaf deserves a shout out for being the rare breed of JVM user who actually posts answers with the exact import needed!

Answer (score 0):

`import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler`

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

`val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("key", "id", "val1", "val2", "val3","score"))
    .setOutputCol("combined")`

```
val dfRes = assembler.transform(df).groupby("id").agg(collect_list($"combined"))
```

Comment: I like this solution but looks like VectorAssembler does not work with StringType.

Comment: yes, it does not indeed, below Asaafs is the easiest solution, alternatively you can use org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{IndexToString, StringIndexer} but I guess it will be too much hustle here

Comment: Thanks. I liked you're solution more because there is no need for the additional column and my dataset has ~150 columns

Answer (score 0):

File Content of my xzy.txt file

```
key id val1 val2 val3
1   a  a1   a2   a3
2   a  a4   a5   a6
3   b  b1   b2   b3
4   b  b4   b5   b6
5   b  b7   b8   b9
6   c  c1   c2   c3
```

Code with Required Output

[image]

Input file Content

[image]